# SqlParameterCollection.Add with a size of -1

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlclient

What does it mean if you add a parameter to a query and set its size to -1?

Example:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = jsonData;
```

Comment: Seems you have code to do it, why don't you tell us what it "appears" to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the size you need to set for fields within a database that have a size of `MAX`  IE. `varchar(max)` / `nvarchar(max)` etc

Comment: I don't think this answers the question of specifically what -1 does? Unless you are saying that -1 is = max, which isn't clear.

Comment: @Harrison apologies I have updated my answer to try and make it clearer.